# Prove that this language is decidable or not

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, computability, turing-machines, decidability

**L = {w#x| w,x ∈ {0, 1}$^*$ and $M_w$ have $BIN^{-1}$(x) different States}**

$M_w$ is the encoded Turing machine.

It is definitely decidable, but i need to show a proof for that.

I thought, that i can use a reduction $A ≤ B$ to show if $A$ is decidable then $B$ is also decidable and $A$ is something like

{w#x| w,x ∈ {0, 1}$^*$ and $M_w$ halts for any x after n steps}

.
But i could not apply such a solution.

Comment: Can you explain what is the $\operatorname{BIN}$ function?

Comment: $BIN^{-1}$ function takes x and convert it to decimal number

Comment: The encoding of a Turing Machine includes a description of Q, a non-empty and finite set of states. Your decider can just check if |Q| = x